# Do mods still merge spam users into the deposit user?

Tags: support

I know that a while ago, instead of outright deleting/destroying newly created users who post spam, they would be suspended and then merged into a single user (https://superuser.com/users/43131/deposit). Do moderators still do that? I'm a little curious.

**Update: That user is now deleted, so clicking on the above link will give you a 404 error.**

Comment: Starting a rollback war with me is a great way to get suspended ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Moderators are no longer able to merge accounts directly. The process for handling spam accounts has also changed significantly since then, and there are alternative methods now that are more effective than merging into the deposit user.

Comment: So it's only SE staff who can merge users now?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi that is correct.