# Why does the Stack Exchange user profile say that this user has a different number of answers from what it says on this site's user profile?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, user-profiles

I'm looking at the user profile page of this user (https://superuser.com/users/43131/) and it says that that user hasn't posted any answers. However, when I look at the same user's profile on Stack Exchange, it says that the user has posted two answers:

[image: user posted two answers]

Why does this apparent discrepancy exist?

Comment: Because its not a real user?

Comment: @Ramhound It's a real user. No joke. Just click on the link that says "more accounts".

Comment: Its a "real" dummy account that isn't used.

Comment: @Ramhound [This is a "real" dummy account that isn't used](http://superuser.com/users/-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user actually posted 870 answers on Super User.

It's a user profile we used to merge other profiles into to get rid of them. We no longer do that.

I would have assumed that you understand this, given your question [Do mods still merge spam users into the deposit user?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8150/do-mods-still-merge-spam-users-into-the-deposit-user)

Comment: Yes, but why does the Stack Exchange profile say that it has two answers? (Side point: the user has accounts on other sites and is named "cyberswan" on them, and it created its newest account on [softwarerecs.se] one week ago)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Can't speak about the two answers, but the linked accounts are automatically created when a new spammer uses an e-mail address that was previously already merged into the big ball o'spam. But the team is taking care of that now.

Comment: @slhck I can see that the user is deleted now.